# Why does Jamie Madrox fall into a coma during "Messiah Complex"?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

In the X-Men storyline ["Messiah Complex"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Messiah_Complex), published by Marvel Comics in 2007, [Jamie Madrox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox) sends one of his duplicates each into two alternate futures with the help of Forge. One of these dies, and Jamie falls into a coma.

Why is that? Has this never happened to him before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jamie Madrox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox) takes on the memories and experiences of his duplicates; likewise he experiences their injuries and damage, though to a lesser degree. For example, when Proteus possessed and killed one of the duplicates, this caused Madrox Prime to collapse in pain. ([According to Marvel.com this is due to "psychic backlash"](http://marvel.com/universe/Multiple_Man).) If a duplicate undergoes an injury, upon merging the merged Jamie typically ends up with an injury half as severe.

So it's consistent with the above that the death of a duplicate could have a severe but less-than-lethal effect on Madrox Prime. (That said, the authors have not been entirely consistent on this over the years, of course.)

Comment: The thing which struck me was that, no one expected him to suffer from the death of a duplicate, nor did Jamie, as it was planned from the start.